# Building websites to run only on iPads and Android Tablets?

Tags: android, html, tablet, viewport

I have HTML5 animated content that I want to be viewed in browswers on iPads and Android tablets.

I have done one version for iPads (Safari) already which works great.

Am I better off designing several different website layout and screen sizes (viewport stupidity), or is it possible to design a single website which adapts the contents to the different browsesr, screen & viewport sizes?

Are there online tutorials & resources for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best practices would be to

- Check for browsers capabilities instead of (brand) sniffing through user agent string.
- Design the most you can as "a single website which adapts the contents to the different browsers, screen & viewport sizes" just like you said. It's easier said than done but is the way forward...
- Manage what you cannot do this way by applying fixes that make sense for target audience. (Like IE conditional comment, which might not be applicable on iOS or Android, but why stop there :)

There are many resources that can be found. Search for the following keywords.
"CSS Media Queries", "Fluid layout", "Responsive Design", ...

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Media queries will allow you to hide and show content on different viewports etc so keeping the same HTML source code but adjusting its visual adderance by linking various CSS style sheets. I tend to use:

```
<!-- MOBILE DEVICES -->
<link href="CSS/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 767px)" />
<!--ANDROID MOBILE FIX-->
<link href="CSS/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" />
<!-- TABLET DEVICES -->
<link href="CSS/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" />
<!--DESKTOP DEVICES -->
<link href="CSS/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1025px)" />
```

Here is a [CSS3 media queries tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

Comment: Sorry, but the "CSS/basic.css" etc are where?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: These files would be the particular css files that you would have developed for each device type individually, had you gone that route. Think of this technique as "single web layout with conditional resolution of device-appropriate CSS." The use of media queries in your template can help in selecting appropriate graphic images/scripts/fonts for smaller devices as well. An excellent recen t resource on these techniques is Implementing Responsive Web Design, by Tim Kadlec.

Comment: it depends you can edit there location e.g. href="CSS/basic.css" this just means that you have a folder named CSS and within that folder is  a file called basic.css the beauty of doing it this way is that the webpage will appear the same for all window sizes on desktop computer and doesn't change when you resize the browser only change the device e.g. view the website on tablets or mobiles etc

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to make fluid/liquid website layouts (based on percentages of screen width/height) that change size depending on screen-size.

If this "animated content" has fixed size elements you are probably going to add some black bars on the sides to compensate for this on Android tablets.

Some front-end frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) handle all the fluidity for you.

Comment: Bootstrap looks very interesting; not sure if it's beyond my knowledge / skill level right now. I will contact them for more info, thanks.

Comment: And yes, there are fixed-size animation frames... (source size 2000 x 600 now) But *which* size to choose for those frame is up to me. Obviously, picking optimal sizes for the different screens would be nice, if only I knew how to pick those sizes!

Comment: You could use jQuery/Javascript to capture the width/height of the browser. I don't know how much experience you have with these kind of things though. http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: From what I have heard, the Nexus/Chrome axis does not report the correct numbers.

Comment: I ran http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ on my Galaxy Nexus and it reports 720 width and 1134 height, which is correct.

Comment: Running http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ in Chrome on Nexus 7 shows 601 x 794. Dolphin shows 602 (window.outerWidth is 800), and 906 (window.outerHeight is 1205)